# Как в 1С удалить лишний пробел, подставленный из номера документа?

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
 ИмяДокумента = КаталогПред.ИмяБезРасширения+" "+ВыбратьНомерДокумента+".xls";
```

Выводит:

```
C:\Users\ПользовательПК\Desktop\Выгрузка\Контр .xls
```

Пробовал:
`СтрЗаменить(ВыбратьНомерДокумента, Символы.НПП, "")`
такой:

```
СокрЛП(ВыбратьНомерДокумента)
```

такой:
`СтрЗаменить(ВыбратьНомерДокумента, " ", "")`

без результата. Что сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш пробел откуда берется, а не из номера документа.
[image: Вот]

Попробуй

Вариант 1:

`ИмяДокумента = СтрШаблон("%1 %2.xls", КаталогПред.ИмяБезРасширения, ВыбратьНомерДокумента);`

Вариант 2:

`Параметры = Новый Структура("ИмяКаталога, НомерДокумента", КаталогПред.ИмяБезРасширения, ВыбратьНомерДокумента);`

`ИмяДокумента = СтроковыеФункцииКлиентСервер.ВставитьПараметрыВСтроку("[ИмяКаталога]  [НомерДокумента].xls", Параметры);`

Comment: точно, спасибо, думал что для номера документа только пробел, но не для расширения. Другой вопрос, а как сделать чтобы для номера документа только был пробел?

Comment: Напишите пример, как в итоге вы хотите видеть. По описанию не понимаю что хотите.

Comment: Я не так написал оказывается, сейчас документ выглядит так: `C:\Users\ПользовательПК\Desktop\Выгрузка\Контр НомерДок .xls`, а нужно чтобы было так: `C:\Users\ПользовательПК\Desktop\Выгрузка\Контр НомерДок.xls`, т.е. после `НомерДок` не должно быть пробела.

Comment: 1. `ИмяДокумента = СтрШаблон("%1 %2.xls", КаталогПред.ИмяБезРасширения, ВыбратьНомерДокумента);`

2. 
`Параметры = Новый Структура("ИмяКаталога, НомерДокумента", КаталогПред.ИмяБезРасширения, ВыбратьНомерДокумента);`
`ИмяДокумента = СтроковыеФункцииКлиентСервер.ВставитьПараметрыВСтроку("[ИмяКаталога]  [НомерДокумента].xls", Параметры);`

Comment: Обновил ответ, так как в комментариях нет нормального форматирования кода.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает

Comment: @ВадимЧиркунов, пожалуйста.